# How to disable multiple logins for same user account while JWT Tokens with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, jhipster

How to disable multiple logins for same user account while JWT Tokens with Spring boot.  How to achieve this in JHIPSTER app.
I'm using Jhipster 3.12.2.

Answer (score -1):

In spring security you can configure session management and control the maximum number of sessions for a single user in this way:

```java
sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

`maximumSessions` controls the maximum number of sessions for a user. The default is to allow any number of users.

`maxSessionsPreventsLogin` if sets to true, prevents a user from authenticating when the `maximumSessions` has been reached.

So in jhipster app you can config to prevent multiple logins for same user in the `SecurityConfiguration` file like this:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/websocket/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .and()
        .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter())
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);

}
```

Comment: This is allowing maximum of only one user. It doesn't fit for the question. My Qn is I should not allow same user logging from browser, desktop/laptop, tab or mobile or from any other device simultaneously. only one active session for every user at any point in time.

Comment: @KarunakerReddyV, It's not only for one user! It controls the maximum number of sessions for every user.

Comment: I've tested this and found that when one user is logged-in and it is not allowing any other user to login.

Comment: @KarunakerReddyV I've tested and I could login with multiple users but every user could login 1 time! for more info please visit https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html

Comment: this is not a solution for JWT.